# Did the site disable changing the link colour when the question is looked at?

Tags: bug

In the past (on all SO sites, including this one), when I clicked on a link it changes colour to signify that I've viewed it.  This allows me easily to see where I left off reading prior in the list as well as if I've viewed questions before.

I noticed today I clicked into a question and there was no colour change on return to list or after hard refresh of the page.  Was this a chance (intentional or otherwise)?

I did not have the same problem on Stack Overflow (main), rpg or arqade (3/3 I checked) so seems to be here specifically, thus assuming not my webbrowser either (which currently is Safari on MacOSX if it matters).

Comment: I discovered today that if I type in the URL of the website in Safari this functions correctly but if I use the frequently visited section it doesn't.  That lends me even further to believe this is a Safari bug (tho it may affect other browsers as this feature exists across them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope it is still there for me.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I checked and it does work in Chrome.  Weird other SO sites work.  Offchance were you using Safari too?  That'd clue me if it was some sort of setting.

Comment: @joedragons No I was using chrome and sometimes I use vivaldi

Comment: For the record this workaround worked for me in Safari: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7490591.  I'm going to assume it's Safari somehow, tho the blue colours are not the same, so I don't understand how it would be.  Maybe a Safari bug.  Thanks for the tip tho, accepting answer.